# Python Matrix Cyberpunk Solver

Tags: python

I have input data like this:

```
4              #length of way
BD 1C BD 55    #way
5              #matrix size (5x5 now)
1C BD 1C 55 55 #matrix
55 55 55 1C 1C
E9 1C 55 55 E9
BD 1C 1C 1C BD
55 BD E9 55 1C
```

I need to print the right way to solving matrix. The rules of solving are this:

1. At this input i have a `BD 1C BD 55` code to find. I take the first line (`1C BD 1C 55 55`) and find `BD`in it. It is the 2nd element
2. Now I take the 2nd vertical (`BD 55 1C 1C BD`) and find `1C` in it. It can be 3rd and 4th. And that's my problem for now. The program should check the 3rd way and the 4th. As you can see, there is no `BD` element in the third line (`E9 1C 55 55 E9`), but there is a `BD` element at the fourth line (`BD 1C 1C 1C BD)`. So it is the first element.
3. Now i continue doing finding this untill i get all way. So i print the way and the answer for this input is `2 4 1 2`. If there is more than one answer, I can choose any one.
   [Here is the visualisating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFEHZ.png)

Here is my code.

```
arrway = []
waylen = int(input())
wayin = list(map(str, input().split()))
for i in range(waylen):
    arrway.append(wayin[i])
k = int(input())
array = [[0 for j in range(k)] for i in range(k)]

for i in range(k):
    a = list(map(str, input().split()))
    for j in range(k):
        array[i][j] = a[j]
ANS = []
##############
print(array)
# The array for the example is [['1C', 'BD', '1C', '55', '55'], ['55', '55', '55', '1C', '1C'], ['E9', '1C', '55', '55', 'E9'], ['BD', '1C', '1C', '1C', 'BD'], ['55', 'BD', 'E9', '55', '1C']]
#############
currentNum = 0
currentPos = 0
for i in range(waylen):
    currentElement = arrway[currentNum]
    if i % 2 == 0:
        for jk in range(k):  # horizontal
            if array[currentPos][jk] == currentElement:
                ANS.append(jk + 1)

                currentPos = jk
                currentNum += 1
    else:
        for jkl in range(k):  # vertical
            if array[jkl][currentPos] == currentElement:
                ANS.append(jkl + 1)

                currentPos = jkl
                currentNum += 1
##########
print(ANS)
# the ANS for example is [2, 3, 4, 1, 2] but no [2, 4, 1, 2]. 
##########
```

So, as you can see, the problem is about checking the right way of the several elements. Now my code have the two-dimensional array of matrix.

Hope you can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input is reasonably small, then you can try using recursion (however if the input is big, you might fail with a stack overflow).

You first call `find_on_row` giving it the whole list of way elements, the whole array, and also indices of the current way element we find (in the beginning it's 0) and the index of a row you want to search over (in the beginning it's 0, as you said).

`find_on_row` goes over all elements in the specified row, and for each elements that is equal to the needed way element it calls `find_on_col` function (since you have `BD` only once on the first row, the function `find_on_col` is called once with this column.

`find_on_col` does the similar thing - it goes over all elements in the specified column, looks for the next way elements and calls `find_on_row` for each match (2 times in this case, since `1C` can be found twice on the first column.

These two calls now search the answer separately, one from the 3rd row, the other from the 4th row. They go until either the whole way is found (i.e. `way_index` is the maximum possible), or if there's no match for the current way elements (so no answer from this search path).

```
def find_on_row(way, array, way_index, row_index):
    if way_index == len(way): # found answer
        return []
    for col_index in range(len(array[0])):
        if array[row_index][col_index]== way[way_index]:
            candidate_answer = find_on_col(way, array, way_index + 1, col_index)
            if not candidate_answer is None: # unwind answer
                return [col_index] + candidate_answer
    return None

def find_on_col(way, array, way_index, col_index):
    if way_index == len(way): # found answer
        return []
    for row_index in range(len(array)):
        if array[row_index][col_index] == way[way_index]:
            candidate_answer = find_on_row(way, array, way_index + 1, row_index)
            if not candidate_answer is None: # unwind answer
                return [row_index] + candidate_answer
    return None

way = ['BD', '1C', 'BD', '55']

array = [['1C', 'BD', '1C', '55', '55'], ['55', '55', '55', '1C', '1C'], ['E9', '1C', '55', '55', 'E9'], ['BD', '1C', '1C', '1C', 'BD'], ['55', 'BD', 'E9', '55', '1C']]

print(f'Starting from first row the answer is {find_on_row(way, array, 0, 0)}')
# Starting from first row the answer is [1, 3, 0, 1]
```

It prints indices starting from 0, so to get your desired output you can increment each value by 1 (I don't do that, because it's more convenient to work with indices starting from 0)